# How to prove that any symmetric matrix is associated to self adjoint endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

How can I prove that any symmetric matrix is associated to a self-adjoint endomorphism in a finite dimensional euclidean vector space $(V, \cdot)$?

Starting from $A^{T}=A$

I don't know the correct procedure to get to 
$(AX)^{T} Y= X^{T} (AY)$

Which is

$f(x) \cdot y= x \cdot f(y)$

If I consider an orthonormal basis and two vectors $x$ and $y$.

Can I multiply both sides of $A^{T}=A$ for $X^{T}$ and $Y$? Is this a correct step?

Do I have to I impose the equality true **for any** $X$, $Y$ and $A$ to do it?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You must allow every $X,Y$ pair, especially when $X$ is the column vector will all entries $0$ except a single $1$ in position $i,$ and  $Y$ is the column vector will all entries $0$ except a single $1$ in position $j.$

Comment: Ok thanks! I know I have to do it when from $(AX)^{T} Y= X^{T} (AY)$ I want to show that $A= A^{T}$ but I was not sure that in the opposite way I must to impose it valid **for any** $X$ and $Y$ too

Answer (score 2):

For any two matrices $A$ and $B$,  $(AB)^{T}=B^{T}A^{T}$ when the multiplication makes sense.

So $(AX)^{T}Y=(X^{T}A^{T})Y=(X^{T}A)Y=X^{T}(AY)$.

The fact that taking transposes reverses the order or multiplication can be verified by the definition of matrix multiplication: $c_{i,j}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}a_{i,k}b_{k,j}$ when $A=(a_{i,j})$, $B=(b_{i,j})$, and $AB=C=(c_{i,j})$.